# MongoDB Atlas. trying to establish link with atlas DB

Tags: mongoose, web-development-server, mongodb-atlas

got a link from Atlas and copied it to terminal and entered password to establish connect as instructed in "Udemy". Please check the error shown in the terminal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHWMR.png)

Answer (score 0):

do like four steps

1. network Access
2. add IP Access
3. 0.0.0.0/0 or your ip
4. Confirm

[image]

**Note**: you can allow access from anywhere from MongoDB Atlas with 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: I have already done this. It was working fine after connection to mongodb Atlas after deploying it to heroku it was successfully built after that it's giving error. I think it's a run time error comming up when hosted in heroku can't find out where.